# Linear Algebra Basis Help?

Tags: linear-algebra

How would I write a basis for this matrix? $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end {array} \right)$ I want it in the form of $x(t)= t(?,?,?)$

What I tried was letting $x3 = t$, since the last row is zeros, then $x3$ is a free variable. 
But then what would $x2 = ?$ HELP PLEASE :)

The answer is $x(t)=(0,1,0)$

Comment: Basis for a matrix? Bases are for vector spaces; a matrix doesn't have a basis. Are you looking for a basis of its nullspace?

Comment: $y$ must be free, because its column is null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should let $y$ be free. Then $y = t$, and the $1$st and $3$rd row imply that $x = z = 0$. So your solution $x(t) = (0, t, 0) = t(0, 1, 0)$, and the basis of your solution set is: $(0, 1, 0)$

Comment: I love you so much :)